# EasyPHP mysql module open button blank page

Tags: mysql, easyphp

everything has always worked but from today without any reason if I connect to the dashboard and I click on the open button related to the module mysql it refuses me the connection, it doesn't show me anything.

My web application works properly even after several machine or process restarts and I don't see any slowdown.
From cmd I can easily connect to the database and do everything.

So I can say that not only the graphical part of the database management works but I would like to understand why I saw that I didn't touch anything from one day to the other.

The configuration remained so, therefore, always on 127.0.0.1 on port 80 and the database on 3306

Comment: Something has necessarily changed on your system.Did install a new software ? Did your uninstall something ? Any error message ?

Comment: Well, first time i've got this error i don't know why. A few days ago I've uninstalled all and installed 64bit version (devser 17 + php + mysql + phpmyadmin all last version). When I've ended all installation I've try to load phpmyadmin and it's work. Then I've changed all .ini, my php web application works but phpmyadmin stop to works.This step was crucial but last installation i never modify ini for about  6 months

Comment: Where I must to see for any king of error? no error into apache log, mysql only 3 warning and 2 notes. Repete my web application works very well only myphpadmin for see database not work